# Link Sonar's quality profile with XML configs from github

Tags: xml, github, sonarqube, sca

We use Github as VCS and Sonar for SCA tool. Is there a possibility to link quality profile config files (checkstyle.xml, pmd.xml etc) in a way to be taken from the github repository and then used by the Sonar when building our app?

This would result in less things to change/watch out for when we change anything in our profiles.

Comment: What else do you have to change when you modify your quality profile in SonarQube?

Comment: I mean I would simply like to make Sonar use the same config files which are on our repo. Sometimes rules are changed, some custom are added or some that make less sense are deleted. In this way also all developers know that once they do any changes in config files and commit them - they will also be automatically used by Sonar.

Comment: OK. Why do you use checkstyle, pmd, etc. configuration files as you're using SonarQube?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Probably the thing is we use plain, old, regular Sonar, not SonarQube and maybe it's different there?
Our quality profile consists of PMD and Checkstyle rules so that we can also use these rules in our IDEs (STS, IntelliJ etc). It allows even earlier checks of code quality by developers during implementation.